# UNET unity project - second connected client doesn't seem to spawn properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been struggling with this for a couple days now. My goals was to have each logged in player be assigned a role in controlling a common GameObject. (In this case a tank). I overrode the NetworkManager with the following scripts: (https://github.com/ChargerIIC/TankPrototype/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Player/PlayerManager.cs) 
(https://github.com/ChargerIIC/TankPrototype/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Player/PlayerInstance.cs).

The first application instance (the host) has the code working perfectly fine. The player chooses to host and the user is assigned to the 'driver' role, attached to the right place, and get the right input controller. The second application instance connects as a client and seems to spawn without going through the OnServerAddPlayer code at all - instead the instance of that player object on the *hosting application* seems to get the code fired off and applied.

As an example I have a pair of screenshots of this in action. In this one, my unity debugger is the first application instance (host) and I'm using a built exe as the client[image: As Local Host]

The objects all seem to spawn properly and the second player is placed in the correct place in the hierarchy. Annoyingly, the local host player now has both input controllers and is controlling both position simultaneously.

In this screenshot, I've used the compiled .exe to host and the debugger is attached as a local client:
[image: As Local Client]

Here the playerobjects don't have the place in the hierarchy set and don't have the needed controllers. The second player can't see the shared object (the tank) or interact with it at all.

I'm new to UNET and I'm certain there must be something I'm missing, but after digging through the unity docs I haven't been able to figure out what. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong or what I could check next?

Comment: So, the role of the second player isnt getting set?

Comment: The second player's gameobject seems to exist in two places - on the first (hosting) player's computer it gets set, but not on the second player's computer. The second player doesn't seem to pass through the initialization logic at all.